# Is UIImageView of type UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I am new to Objective-c. a loop is created to iterate through items or entries of UIView that are displayed in the storyboard. the storyboard contains a UIScrollView and the UIScrollView encompass 7UIViews and 2 UIImageView. 
the loop I have in the code, iterated through 9 entries. 
i expected the loop to iterate through 7 entries as there are UIViews and two UIImageViews.

My question is, is UIImageView is of type UIView?

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Yes. UIView is the base class of all view objects in UIKit

Comment: @Paulw11 so that means, that UIImageview when found in the loop it will be counted or treated as if it is a UIView entry?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "treated as if it is a UIView entry" - the scroll view has 9 subviews. 7 of them are UIView and 2 of them are UIImageView, which is a subclass of UIView.

Comment: @Paulw11 i mean "to be considered"..i hope it will be clear

Comment: Still not really. A `UIImageView` is a `UIView` subclass. Like if you had a pen that contained animals and 3 were cows and 3 were sheep. If someone asked how many animals were in the pen you would say 6. That does png mean that a cow is a sheep, they are just kinds of animals.  In your loop you can test the type of the object to identify whether it is a UIView or a UIImageView or a UIButton...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, a UIImageView is of type UIView

```
UIKIT_EXTERN API_AVAILABLE(ios(2.0)) @interface UIImageView : UIView
```

and UIView is of type

```
UIKIT_EXTERN API_AVAILABLE(ios(2.0)) @interface UIView : UIResponder <NSCoding, UIAppearance, UIAppearanceContainer, UIDynamicItem, UITraitEnvironment, UICoordinateSpace, UIFocusItem, UIFocusItemContainer, CALayerDelegate>
```

and UIResponder is of type

```
UIKIT_EXTERN API_AVAILABLE(ios(2.0)) @interface UIResponder : NSObject <UIResponderStandardEditActions>
```

so UIImageView inherits everything from NSObject, UIResponder, and UIView and is of type NSObject, UIResponder, and UIView

good luck